# fix for seeds labs android rooting

Tags: android, security, ota, over-the-air

I am doing android rooting seeds lab following each step very closely, I have started project from scratch 2 to 3 times all codes are good, but when uploading task2.zip and running update-binary, It gives this error as in the screenshot.

I tried to do all steps as given in manual and all codes are correct, both ubuntu and android machine are provided by seeds labs.
it
seed@recovery:/tmp$ unzip task2.zip

```
archive: task2.zip creating: task2/ 
creating: task2/META-INF/ 
creating: task2/META-INF/com/ 
creating: task2/META-INF/com/google/ 
creating: task2/META-INF/com/google/android/ 
inflating: task2/META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary 
inflating: task2/META-INF/com/google/android/my_app_process 

seed@recovery:/tmp$ cd task2/META-INF/com/google/android/ 
seed@recovery:/tmp/task2/META-INF/com/google/android$ chmod a+x update-binary seed@recovery:/tmp/task2/META-INF/com/google/android$ sudo ./update-binary
```

[sudo] password for seed:
cannot stat '/android/system/bin/app_process64': No such file or directory cp: cannot stat 'my_process': No such file or directory chmod: cannot access '/android/system/bin/app_process64': No such file or director seed@recoyery:/tmp/taskn2/META-INF/com/google/android$
seed@recovery:/tmp/task2/META-INF/com/google/android$